# media query condition about width or having a class name

Tags: css, media-queries

Can I specify a rule like "all viewports having max width 640px or the body tag(or other tag) having a class named touch" will have the following css rules. Something like:

`@media (max-width: 768px), .touch {
}`

Thanks!

Edit: And because the rules are long I don't want to separate them to 2 parts and repeat the rules in these 2 parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
.touch { background: blue; }
}
```

No you can't do something like @media all and (max-width: 768px) and (.touch=true)
or has class .touch in dom, etc

Here is a list of the acceptable media queries from W3

> width height device-width device-height orientation aspect-ratio
>   device-aspect-ratio color color-index monochrome resolution scan grid
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: That's fast. But your condition is an 'and' not 'or'

Comment: Alright, it seems that we cannot do it. I will accept your answer, but you should remove the code because it's does not do what is asked.